# Why ServiceSecurityContext.Current is null?

Tags: .net, wcf, security, wcf-security

I am not very familiar with WCF REstful Services.

I was trying to test my method -which deletes some records from Db- and whem I call :

ServiceSecurityContext.Current at some point (In order to modify the LastModified property), I am getting NullArgumentException as .Current is null.

I am using Windows authentication.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, authentication is not turned on for the call you're making. Review the binding and service behavior and see if you find the issue there.